# How to use a variable in a FROM statement to change servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I have 3 servers and want 1 script to query them. To do this I thought to use a parameter such as below:

This way I could simply pass in the bit of the server that changes, rather than creating 3 scripts.

My servers for this example are called:

```
[AAA-SERVER-01]
[BBB-SERVER-01]
[CCC-SERVER-01]

DECLARE @server1 VARCHAR(3) = 'AAA'
DECLARE @server2 VARCHAR(3) = 'BBB'
DECLARE @server3 VARCHAR(3) = 'CCC'

SELECT *
FROM [@server1-SERVER-01].DB.dbo.TABLE T1
```

How do I use a variable like this within the FROM. I though to use CONCAT such as the below but it just feels wrong especially when trying to JOIN. Anyway got a cool way of doing this?

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CONCAT('[',@server1,'-SERVER-01].DB.dbo.TABLE T1' ) )
```

Comment: Why not create a variable @sql and write your query into variable? After that just call `EXEC @sql`

Comment: You can't do what you ask. You can't change the table name this way either. Execution plans are built from the index and data statistic information of each table, so changing the table would be equivalent to changing the type in C#. Table names can't be parameters. The same table may have 10 rows on one server and 10M rows on another. This would result in *very* different execution plans

Comment: Your only option really is dynamic Sql. As commented you cannot parameterise DDL, a query's execution plan is pre-baked ie set in stone before it is actually executed, it cannot be changed on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a parameter to replace a literal, and an object name *must* be a literal. You'll need to use dynamic SQL for this, for example:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@server1 + N'-SERVER-01') + N'.DB.dbo.[TABLE] T1;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that makes a lot of sense. As my query is rather large and I'm all that familiar with d-sql, I'm just going to do an IF and list the code 3 times with changing server names. Given me something else to think about, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using SQLCmd mode from SSMS, save your script to a file and execute thus:

```
:CONNECT [AAA-SERVER-01]
USE DB1;
:r C:\SqlScript\YourScript.sql
GO
:CONNECT [BBB-SERVER-01]
USE DB1;
:r C:\SqlScript\YourScript.sql
GO
:CONNECT [CCC-SERVER-01]
USE DB1;
:r C:\SqlScript\YourScript.sql
GO
```